# EXTjs getEl() fails before showing the element

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

Good day all.

In EXTjs, probably 4.x version, I have a menu with a couple of levels of sub-menus
I'd like to add a data attribute to some of those sub-menus and actually I can do this with no problems with:
Ext.getCmp("notificationMenu").getEl().set({"data-notifynumber": 4});

but this is working only for the first element of the menu (to be clear, the element that is shown upon loading.
For any other element of the menu, first of all I have to click the menu to show all the sub-menu and only at that time I can use the getEl() function, otherwise this error is shown:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

I understand that I'd need to... show? render? well, "do something" to those sub elements in order to have them in the dom properly... I attach part of the code:

this is part of the menu I create:

```
xtype: 'button',
            id:"notificationMenu",
            hidden: false,              
            reference: 'userType',
            style: 'color: #ffffff;width:58px;height:58px;',
            glyph: 0xf0f3,
            menu:{
                border:0,
                menuAlign: 'tr-br?',
                bodyStyle: {
                    background: '#3e4752',
                },
                items:[
                {
                    text:"TASKS",
                    disabled:true
                },
                {
                    text:"Campaigns",
                    data_id:"me_campaigns",
                    glyph:0xf0c1,
                    id:"notification_me_campaigns_root",
                    hidden:true,
                    menu:{
                        border:0,
                        menuAlign: 'tr-br?',
                        bodyStyle: {
                            background: '#3e4752',
                        },
                        items:[
                        {
                        text:"Approval",...
```

in this example, if I make after Render:

```
Ext.getCmp("notificationMenu").getEl().set({"data-notifynumber": 10})
```

but if I use

```
Ext.getCmp("notification_me_campaigns_root").getEl().set({"data-notifynumber": 4})
```

the error above is shown. please do you have some advice? may I call a "force render" somehow?

Comment: Wrong way of doing it. Configure the element creation so it sets up the attribute when it gets rendered.

Comment: the function is already called in the afterRender handler, and the attribute must be setted not during the creation but at some itnervals (it is a notification menu so there is a polling and from time to time I had to change the attribute of that menu)

Answer (score 0):

> Try to use [afterrender](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-event-afterrender) to get dom element.

ExtJs [getEl()](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-getEl) Retrieves the top level element representing this component but work when [dom](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.dom.AbstractElement-property-dom) is prepared without [dom](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.dom.AbstractElement-property-dom) creation it will return null.

I have created an [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/28fu) demo hope this will help you to achieve you requirement/solution.

```
var panel = new Ext.panel.Panel({
            renderTo: document.body,
            title: 'A Panel',
            width: 200,
            tools: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Foo',
                menu: {
                    defaults: {
                        handler: function () {
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Successs', 'You have click on <b>data-notifynumber</> ' + this.up('menu').getEl().getAttribute('data-notifynumber'))
                        }
                    },
                    items: [{
                        text: 'Item 1'
                    }, {
                        text: 'Item 2',
                        menu: {
                            listeners: {
                                afterrender: function () {
                                    this.getEl().set({
                                        "data-notifynumber": 20//only for example you can put as basis of your requirement
                                    });
                                }
                            },
                            defaults: {
                                handler: function () {
                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Successs', 'You have click on <b>data-notifynumber</> ' + this.up('menu').getEl().getAttribute('data-notifynumber'))
                                }
                            },
                            items: [{
                                text: 'Sub Item 1',

                            }, {
                                text: 'Sub Item 2'
                            }]
                        }
                    }],
                    listeners: {
                        afterrender: function () {
                            this.getEl().set({
                                "data-notifynumber": 10//only for example you can put as basis of your requirement
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
```

Comment: The function that retrieve the elements is already fired into the afterRender of the controller, but I'll try also to put an afterRender handler into the menu itself, I'll let you know.
by the way the problem seems to be related to the render mechanism, it seems that the internal menu is rendered only after the toplevel element is clicked